# newline feature of print command in Python

Tags: python

I am teaching myself how to program in Python, and I have a question about "print".

I know that print statement has a newline "\n" feature embedded into it, but I noticed that whenever my code ends with a print statement, for example,  print("This is the end"), it does not create a newline.

Is it a feature of Python that the newline of the very **last** print statement is suppressed?

p.s. I am using IDLE

Comment: What makes you think that the last print statement doesn't create a newline?

Comment: What are you testing on? Try running `print('This is the end', end='')` and seeing what the result is.

Comment: @AdamSmith If I run a script that has only  print('test') statement, the interpreter spits out 'test' but it does not give me an extra new line

Comment: What happens when you run `echo test`? Linux, Mac, or Windows?

Comment: Show us your code and the output that makes you think it's not printing that last newline.

Comment: IDLE claims another victim! Why do we keep shipping this with Python? :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Python has no such feature. You might be confusing "not printing a newline" with "not ending with a blank space".

For example, in bash, it might look like this:

```
$ cat endline.py
print('line 1')
print('line 2')
$ cat noendline.py
print('line 1')
print('line 2', end='')
$ python3 endline.py
line 1
line 2
$ python3 noendline.py
line 1
line 2$ echo "It did not end in a newline"
It did not end in a newline
$
```

Notice how `noendline.py` exited without any newline and the prompt immediately continued.

This applies in the live interpreter as well:

```
>>> print('Hello world!')
Hello world!
>>> print('Hello world!', end='')
Hello world!>>> # See?
```

Windows (`cmd`) always appends the end of a program with a newline:

```
C:\> python endline.py
line 1
line 2

C:\> python noendline.py
line 1
line 2
C:\>
```

Comment: I am using IDLE and the Shell, but when I type print('Hello World!,end =''), the new command prompt appears in the next line.

Comment: @hl0202 This is due to IDLE being a wrapper around the interpreter and doesn't accurately display what Python outputs. It detects that the output at the end of the command does not end in a newline and appends it automatically. You can run `sys.stdout.write('hello')` (a raw output) in IDLE and it will still append a newline. If you run Python in the terminal, you will not see this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In python, a `\n` is added by [default](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0278/). You can specify what end argument you want concatenated to the end of your print statement in **[Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function)** with the following (*output copied from sublime 3 to demonstrate the newline*):

```
print('Hello World', end='Arg goes here.')
```

**Output:**

```
Hello WorldArg goes here.[Finished in 0.0s] # Notice no newline.
```

Other wise, a  `\n` is default if no value is passed to the keyword argument `end`.

```
print('Hello World')
```

**Output:**

```
Hello World
[Finished in 0.0s]  # Newline by default.
```

Things work slightly differently in **python 2** as `print` is not a function (`\n` *is default*), however you can emulate this behavior in the following way:

```
from __future__ import print_function
print('Hello World', end='\n')
```

**Output:**

```
Hello World
[Finished in 0.0s]  # Newline specified.
```

Here are a few examples in an interactive shell running in Terminal to demonstrate.

**In shell (Python 2):**

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> print('Hello World', end='\n')
Hello World
>>> print('Hello World', end='\n\n')
Hello World

>>> print('Hello World', end='')
Hello World>>>
```

Comment: if you just type print('Hello World') in the Python interpreter(Python Shell), you see the string 'Hello World', and you don't see an extra blank line. You immediately get the prompt >>>. Don't you?

Comment: @hl0202: Why would you expect a blank line? The `print` does print a newline character, which is why the prompt doesn't just continue on the same line as the `print` output.

Comment: @hl0202 yes, but isn't the `>>>` on a new line?

Comment: @jphollowed >>> is still on a new line if you explicitly suppress the new line character by typing print('Hello World', end = '')

Comment: I actually ran the code in sublime to demonstrate the newline, let me update to show the effect more clearly. Added an interactive shell example.

Comment: @hl0202 not in my repr. What are you using?

Comment: @AdamSmith I am using the interactive shell.

Comment: @hl0202 http://imgur.com/a/ZIy5j  this is from typing `python` (well in my case `py -3` since I'm on Windows) at the command prompt. Are you using IDLE? IDLE might act....funky. Ditch it quick.

Comment: @Adam Smith Yes, I am using IDLE

Comment: @hl0202 strongly suggest you stop using IDLE immediately :D. Not sure why it would create that specific issue, but it's generally a rather....*temperamental* repr. [Jupyter](https://ipython.org/) (previously only known as ipython) is a much more full-featured REPR

Comment: I ***can*** reproduce that issue in IDLE.

Comment: @AdamSmith IDLE's great for rapid development and testing of features - I have it mapped to `Super-I` on my system. If I'm doing longer testing and development, Jupyter can't be beat. Do you mean the qtconsole, or the web interface?

Comment: @Kupiakos I've used both, but having a browser window with a notebook open at all times for trying out little snippets of code has become a good habit of mine. I can't think of any way that IDLE would be better than that.